# ReactJS: Javascript fetch works on desktop browsers but returns a 403 error which says (authentication credentials not provided) on IOS safari

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, django, fetch-api

I'm working on a project using Create-react-app with a backend API written in Django(Python) where I used fetch to make my API calls. API calls run fine on android browsers and on desktop browsers but on IOS Browsers(both safari and chrome) the API returns the 403 error with response (authentication credentials not provided). this issue is a bit more tasking for me as it is quite difficult for me to perform remote debugging for IOS using my windows PC. I was only able to view the error due to JavaScript console using chrome://inspect on IOS and consoling the API response to the Iphone's console I would like some help on this issue.

Comment: is your endpoint protected? Can you please put relevant codes that show what you are saying

Comment: Yes my endpoint is protected. after inspecting on safari I discovered that some endpoints which require the same token working on safari while some don't. note this issue is only occuring in safari. It works perfectly fine on chrome